# Convert RTF to Plain Text

Tags: php, regex, rtf

I have an ERP-System which stores text in RTF format and I'm trying to extract the plain text from it.

I've searched through Google and found a solutions like [this one](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_the_clean_text_from_rtf.php) and some other ones which use REGEX replaces but none of them seem to work.  I always get `NULL` or `}}}` or something completely wrong.

Here is the REGEX I tried:

```php
$matches = array('/\{\\\\(.+?)\}/','/\\\\(.+?)\b/');

$row['text'] = preg_replace($matches,'',$row['text']);
```

However it returns: `}}}`

This is the RTF data I have:

```
{\rtf1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Calibri;}{\f1 Arial;}}{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255 ;}{\*\defchp \fs22}{\*\listoverridetable}{\stylesheet {\ql\fs22 Normal;}{\*\cs1\f1\fs20 Default Paragraph Font;}{\*\cs2\sbasedon1\f1\fs20 Line Number;}{\*\cs3\ul\fs22\cf1 Hyperlink;}{\*\ts4\tsrowd\fs22\ql\trautofit1\tscellpaddfl3\tscellpaddl108\tscellpaddfr3\tscellpaddr108\tsvertalt\cltxlrtb Normal Table;}{\*\ts5\tsrowd\sbasedon4\fs22\ql\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrh\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrv\brdrs\brdrw10\trautofit1\tscellpaddfl3\tscellpaddl108\tscellpaddfr3\tscellpaddr108\tsvertalt\cltxlrtb Table Simple 1;}}\nouicompat\splytwnine\htmautsp\sectd\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs20\cf0 Migration Fileserverdaten innerhalb derselben oder einer vertrauten Dom\u228\'e4ne}\f1\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs20\cf0 Anpassung der Laufwerksfreigaben}\f1\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs20\cf0 Freigabenerstellung wie Bestand (weitere Absprachen hierzu m\u246\'f6glich)}\f1\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs20\cf0 Hostname(n) Quellsystem(e):}\f1\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs20\cf0 Hostname Zielsystem:}\f1\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs20\cf0 Bekanntes Datenvolumen:}\f1\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs20\cf0 Clientseitige Nacharbeiten aufgrund fest vergebener Einstellungen}\f1\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs20\cf0 erfolgen nach Aufwand oder durch den Auftraggeber.}\f1\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs20\cf0 Es wird im Besonderen darauf hingewiesen, da\u223\'df Datei- und Ornderberechtigungen 1:1 beibehalten werden. Die Neuvergabe jedweder Datei- oder Ordnerberechtigung kann nach Aufwand und Anweisung des Auftraggebers durchgef\u252\'fchrt werden.}\f1\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs20\cf0 Voraussetzungen zur Zusatzaufwandsfreien Durchf\u252\'fchrung:}\f1\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs20\cf0 Gigabit Switching zwischen allen Quell- und Zielsystemen, Vollzugriff auf den zu migrierenden Datenbestand}\f1\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql\f1\fs20\par}
```

Edit 2019: for all who find this question im using this single-class project since 4 years without a problem
https://github.com/henck/rtf-html-php

Comment: You need to show your attempted code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Can you attach the string you want to replace?

Comment: If possible, post what you want to get out as a result starting from the sample RTF you posted

Comment: the link dont work. here is the weorking url https://github.com/henck/rtf-html-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some brain *force* I got a solution for you:

Try this regex:

```
"{\*?\\.+(;})|\s?\\[A-Za-z0-9]+|\s?{\s?\\[A-Za-z0-9]+\s?|\s?}\s?"
```

which means replace your code with

```
$count = null;    
$matches = array('"{\*?\\.+(;})|\s?\\[A-Za-z0-9]+|\s?{\s?\\[A-Za-z0-9]+\s?|\s?}\s?"');
$row['text'] = preg_replace($matches,'',$row['text'], -1, $count);
```

Comment: Yeah, i modifed it a little and it looks realy good !!!
 
$count = null;

$row['text'] = preg_replace('"{\\*?\\\\.+(;})|\\s?\\\\[A-Za-z0-9]+|\\s?{\\s?\\\\[A-Za-z0-9]+\\s?|\\s?}\\s?"', '', $row['text'], -1, $count);

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Doesn't the regex what you expect or do you retrieve an error?

Answer (score 4):

I am posting a general solution to this issue for other guys jumped here.

```
public static function converToPlain($text){
    $text = preg_replace('"{\*?\\\\.+(;})|\\s?\\\[A-Za-z0-9]+|\\s?{\\s?\\\[A-Za-z0-9‹]+\\s?|\\s?}\\s?"', '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find an Rtf text extractor here :

[www.rtftools.net](http://www.rtftools.net/index.php)

Here is an example on how to use it :

```
include ( 'path/to/RtfTexter.phpclass' ) ;

$doc = new RtfTexter ( 'sample.rtf' ) ;
echo $doc -> AsString ( ) ;               // Echo text contents to stdout
$doc -> SaveTo ( 'sample.txt' ) ;         // Save text contents to file 'sample.txt'
```

Comment: FYI the link to www.rtftools.net no longer works :(

Answer (score 1):

Hello guys i'm writing this code read rtf file plain text this code working 100%

PHP Code there :

```
$text = file_get_contents('testfile.rtf');
if (!strlen($text)) {
 echo "bad file";
 exit();

}
// we'll try to fix up the parts of the rtf as best we can
// clean up the file a little to simplify parsing
$text=str_replace("\r",' ',$text); // returns
$text=str_replace("\n",' ',$text); // new lines
$text=str_replace('  ',' ',$text); // double spaces
$text=str_replace('  ',' ',$text); // double spaces
$text=str_replace('  ',' ',$text); // double spaces
$text=str_replace('  ',' ',$text); // double spaces
$text=str_replace('} {','}{',$text); // embedded spaces
// skip over the heading stuff
$j=strpos($text,'{',1); // skip ahead to the first part of the header

$loc=1;
$t="";

$ansa="";
$len=strlen($text);
getpgraph(); // skip by the first paragrap

while($j<$len) {
 $c=substr($text,$j,1);
 if ($c=="\\") {
 // have a tag
 $tag=gettag();
 if (strlen($tag)>0) {
 // process known tags
 switch ($tag) {
 case 'par':
 $ansa.="\r\n";
 break;
 // ad a list of common tags
 // parameter tags
 case 'spriority1':
 case 'fprq2':
 case 'author':
 case 'operator':
 case 'sqformat':
 case 'company':
 case 'xmlns1':
 case 'wgrffmtfilter':
 case 'pnhang':
 case 'themedata':
 case 'colorschememapping':
 $tt=gettag();
 break;
 case '*':
 case 'info':
 case 'stylesheet':
 // gets to end of paragraph
 $j--;
 getpgraph();
 default:
 // ignore the tag
 }
 }
 } else {
 $ansa.=$c;
 }
 $j++;
}
$ansa=str_replace('{','',$ansa);
$ansa=str_replace('}','',$ansa);
echo "<pre>$ansa</pre>";

function getpgraph() {
 // if the first char after a tag is { then throw out the entire paragraph
 // this has to be nested
 global $text;
 global $j;
 global $len;
 $nest=0;
 while(true) {
 $j++;
 if ($j>=$len) break;
 if (substr($text,$j,1)=='}') {
 if ($nest==0) return;
 $nest--;
 }
 if (substr($text,$j,1)=='{') {
 $nest++;
 }
 }
 return;
}

function gettag() {
 // gets the text following the / character or gets the param if it there
 global $text;
 global $j;
 global $len;
 $tag='';
 while(true) {
 $j++;
 if ($j>=$len) break;
 $c=substr($text,$j,1);
 if ($c==' ') break;
 if ($c==';') break;
 if ($c=='}') break;
 if ($c=="\\") {
 $j--;
 break;
 }
 if ($c=="{") {
 //getpgraph();
 break;
 }
 if ((($c>='0')&&($c<='9'))||(($c>='a')&&($c<='z'))||(($c>='A')&&($c<='Z'))||$c=="'"||$c=="-"||$c=="*" ){
 $tag=$tag.$c;
 } else {
 // end of tag
 $j--;
 break;
 }
 }
 return $tag;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried @Anurag Prashant suggestion but it didn't work sometimes. For instance, this rtf wasn't converted properly:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1036{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.15.1515;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\f0\fs18 - test\cf0\par
}
```

Here is a php regex that seems to be working better:

```php
/(\{.*\})|}|(\\\\(?!')\S+)/m
```

```php
public static function converToPlain($text)
{
    $text = preg_replace("/(\{.*\})|}|(\\\\(?!')\S+)/m", '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: FYI there's a syntax error in your regexp (both codes above), but I don't understand regexp enough to tell where. (unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR))

Comment: I've edited the answer, I forgot to use double quote instead of simple quote

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had to do something similar recently, and the various answers on this page were of great help. However none of them covered my needs completely, so I had to combine several of them and then add a little of my own.

The code below:

- converts RTF to TXT (not HTML)
- deals with accented or special characters (é, ç, etc)
- also extracts PNG images that might be enclosed in the RTF code

My code only deals with a subset of special characters that were relevant for me, but I include a link to a page that lists all of them.

PNG images are extracted, then reinserted as HTML images at the end of the text, a bit like email attachments. It's not perfect but it was good enough for my needs. Also, I don't know how other image formats work, but I suspect my code can easily be adapted for JPG etc.

```
$plain = $rtfSource;

// we have to remove all line breaks, otherwise
// the RTF>TXT regexp below doesn't work correctly.
$plain = preg_replace( '/\r|\n/', '', $plain);

// extract the images
// example: {\pict\pngblip\picw1166\pich190\picwgoal8071\pichgoal1315 89504e470d0a1a0a00...454e44ae426082}
// the hexadecimal code for the image starts after the
// whitespace and runs until the first } that we encounter.
// then it has to be converted into base64.
$imgHtml = '';
$imgMatches = array();
$imgRegex = '/{\\\\pict\\\\pngblip\\\\[a-z0-9]+\\\\[a-z0-9]+\\\\[a-z0-9]+\\\\[a-z0-9]+ ([a-z0-9]+)}/';
preg_match_all($imgRegex, $plain, $imgMatches);
if (count($imgMatches[1])) {
    for ($i=0; $i < count($imgMatches[1]); $i++) {
        $imgHtml .= '<img src="data:image/png;base64, ' . base64_encode(pack('H*', $imgMatches[1][$i])) . '">';
    }
}

// remove those images (or else their hex code is still displayed as text)
$plain = preg_replace($imgRegex, '', $plain);

// RTF>TXT (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42525858/357546)
$plain = preg_replace('"{\*?\\\\.+(;})|\\s?\\\[A-Za-z0-9]+|\\s?{\\s?\\\[A-Za-z0-9‹]+\\s?|\\s?}\\s?"', '', $plain);

// special characters; for a full list, see:
// https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/rtf-pocket-guide/9781449302047/ch04.html
$plain = str_replace("\'3f", '?', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'80", '€', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'a8", '¨', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'ab", '«', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'ae", '®', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'b0", '°', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'bb", '»', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'c4", 'Ä', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'c9", 'É', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'d6", 'Ö', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'dc", 'Ü', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'df", 'ß', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'e0", 'à', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'e2", 'â', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'e4", 'ä', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'e7", 'ç', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'e8", 'è', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'e9", 'é', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'ea", 'ê', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'eb", 'ë', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'ee", 'î', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'f4", 'ô', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'f6", 'ö', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'f8", 'ø', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'fb", 'û', $plain);
$plain = str_replace("\'fc", 'ü', $plain);

// a bit of cleaning
$plain = trim($plain);
$plain = preg_replace('/^-0 /', '', $plain);
$plain .= $imgHtml;

echo $plain;
```